# Favorite Tags - exclude existing tags from tag add lookup list?

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-watching

I really like the tags feature and I have a lot of both favorite and ignored tags.

I like tags so much that I have over 50 favorites!

However this volume of tags has become a problem when I want to add new ones in a fashion that works well for me on other sites.

The problem is that if a tag is already is in my list (of favorites), it also gets shown in the list of values for adding a new tag.

So, for many people this would not be a problem at all.  They might have 10 tags, they can see them all right there, if they try and add a duplicate it blinks (neat!) and a duplicate isn't created.  No problem.

My issues however goes like this:

I like to add tags from the entire list of tags.  For instance I want top add a lot of tags for git, so I want to add gitx, git-svn, git-branch, git-bash, etc, etc.

I would like to start typing the name, e.g. 'git' and I would like to see a list of the various git... tags.  This works now but the list includes tags that I already have - and due to the volumne of tags I already have, the 'existing' tags are actually off-screen, scrolled up past where I am.  Also as the  suggest list only holds 6 tag suggestions, if all the suggestions are tags that I already have, then this isn't helping me much.

My personal workflow on various sites is to to type the beginning of the thing, in this case git, pick a selection (tag in this case), then type 'git' again to see what's 'left' in the list (universe of tags in this case).  This process works great for me on several other sites.

Would it make sense for new tags selection to work that way?  I suspect that there are reasons or preferences for existing tags to show in the list.  For me it would work better if they didn't but I'm posting here to see what the community thinks :)

Comment: Why not just add `git*` to favorite all of them?

Comment: Ah, I can use wildcards in tags? I didn't know that!  Nifty!  That does help although for an area that has a lot of tags - and git is one of them, if I only want a subset of 10 from the 50, git* wouldn't work.  Yeah I could do git* for favorite tags and then exclude the 40 with ignored tags, but that's a lot of hoops to g through.